# something better than httrack to download files?

Tags: automation, download

I am trying to download documents (pdf, tiff, images) from webpages that have javascript and frames in them. example: http://127.0.0.1/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/mainFrame.cgi

'httrack --get-files' didn't download any, are there other ways you may think of? another program? will I have to write that program myself?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with httrack.  It's a professional-grade spider.  If you want something friendlier, try webhttrack; it's got a pretty interface.  Also, posting a link to localhost doesn't actually give us an example of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wget ?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget

Comment: well, I know about wget, but it didn't work well with this URL (I simply used wget without options)

Comment: You want to download the resources [images, etc] found on the page you posted ?

Comment: Yes, when you click on Document server, there are many  pdf documents I want to download automatically...